# how to properly escape freemaker markups in templates

Tags: java, freemarker

I have one template "main.ftlh" which import another "template.ftlh" (which include "partialView.ftlh")

"main.ftlh"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
        <body>
            <#import "template.ftlh" as my>
            ${my.selectOption('someKey')}
        </body>
</html>
```

"template.ftlh"

```
<#assign exampleData = {"someKey" : 
"<p> 
    This is some simple value: ${some.name} // ${some.name} equals "SOME_LOADED_VALUE"
    <#include "partialView.ftlh">

    //someData - from external java object e.g. contains ["firstText", "secondText"]
    <#list someData as data>                
        <#if data.description?has_content>
            <p>
                This is description: ${data.description}.
            </p>
        </#if>
    </#list>
</p>",
"otherKey" : "<p>other value</p>",
....
....
}>

<#function selectOption find="">
    <#list exampleData?keys as data>
        <#if data == find>
            <#assign result = exampleData[data]>
        </#if>
    </#list>
    <#return result>
</#function>
```

"partialView.ftlh"

```
This is example of content
```

and now how to properly escape all freemaker tags so that will be returned something like this:

```
This is some simple value: SOME_LOADED_VALUE
This is example of content
This is description: firstText
This is description: secondText
```